# QT auto save screenshot with naming template

Tags: c++, qt, save, screenshot, autosave

I want to save multiple screenshot every 10 second with different name,

[i want to save like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNZ7q.png)

> here my current code

```
      QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
      QPixmap pic  = screen->grabWindow(0);
      pic.save("C:/Users/Coding/Desktop/img/desktop_1.png");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format a QString to your file name and append a counter at the end, like this:

```
int counter = 1;
auto fileName = QString("C:/Users/Coding/Desktop/img/desktop_%1.png").arg(counter);
counter++;
pic.save(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this functionality into a class.
Add static counter to your class (for example `static long long counter {0};`)
Declare something like: `QString m_path_to_image;`
change your code to

```
pic.save(path_to_image.arg(m_counter));
```